# cannot clone Saas landing page

Tags: asp.net

instructions in "https://aka.ms/MasteringTheMarketplace" for cloning Saas landing page from "**\saas\lab-code\begin\SaaSLabsBegin.sln" in Visual Studio 2022. The clone fails with the message "does not exist".